# Place a dot between links in navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I place a dot between links in navigation? I am using Bootstrap if it matters

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VKoWea

Using following code a dot will go in new line:

```
li:after {
    content: '\00B7';
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

I don't want a dot to behave as a link so I am not satisfied with this:

```css
li a:after {
  content: '\00B7';
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><a href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `.` after `link` ?

Comment: The links have `display:block`, so you need to change that if you want other content in normal flow on the same "line".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position the dot `absolute` to force it behind the list item.

```
li:after {
    content: '\00B7';
    padding-left: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 14px;
    right: 8px;
}
```

Your problem happens due to the `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` on your a element. this enlarges the initial `<li>` and aligns the `:after` content to the bottom of it.